# xPages - session.getDatabase not returning value

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a test database on my PC that has a drop-down field listing all our clients. I'm now trying to redirect it to the database containing this information on the server. (I load it into a session variable in the beforePageLoad event which the drop-down uses)

```
var cSrv = profileDoc.getItemValueString("RESQServer");
var cFile = profileDoc.getItemValueString("RESQFile");
var cDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(cSrv,cFile);
var cView:NotesView = cDb.getView("(Client)");
var cDoc:NotesDocument = cView.getDocumentByKey("All Others");
sessionScope.put("ClientList",cDoc.getItemValue("Client"));
```

I've printed cSrv and cFile and verified the correct server and filename is there. This bombs on the cDb.getView statement.

```
Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.getView(string)
null
    29:     var cDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(cSrv,cFile);
->  30:     var cView:NotesView = cDb.getView("(Client)");
```

Setting anonymous to be editor in the ACL did'nt help. I must be missing something blindingly obvious.....

Comment: Add a few print statements to make sure your vars cSrv and cFile are getting the correct value. (if you haven't already)

Comment: Already did that. They are correct.

Comment: Does the cDb object return anything else like the database title in a print statement.

Comment: Yes, it did exacly that print ("Database="+cDb) returns just the database name.

Comment: Good, then line 29 is working.  Check your view to see if the name is correct, or alternatively create a NotesDocumentCollection and get at your document that way.

Comment: Doh! The view should have been (Clients). Corrected this, same error, same line

Comment: Can you add the view as a datasource to a sample page?

Comment: Also check that the "(Clients)" view is sorted.  I would think if it was not, the next line would fail, not line 30, but trying to navigate an unsorted view is one of the most common mistakes in Notes.

Comment: Yup the view is sorted. This is something that works great on the Lotus Form side. xPages just isn't cooperating.

Comment: Maximum internet access in ACL?

Comment: yes, check ACL or do this:
var col:NotesDocumentCollection = db.search("SELECT your forumla lanaguage selection formula");
var doc:NotesDocument = col.getFirstDocument();

Comment: @stwissel - I'm able to add it as a datasource and even add the view to the page. It see's the 2 columns correctly labeled. When I try to run it I get; Unable to open database: {servername}!!{databasename} anonymous is in the ACL and has editor privilege

Comment: Try the notes URL approach.  You actually can go directly after the view. Saves you a step. The notes URL of a database is visible in the property box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have an Access issue and are not opening the database as a result. If the "RESQServer" is NOT the same as the current server you need to make sure that server allows the current server access in the `Server Document - Security Tab - Access Server Section - Trust Servers line`.

If the Trust Servers is correctly set or you are on the same server then perhaps the ACL of the target database is missing the name of the user or a group that contains the user. Finally check the `ACL Advanced tab` and make sure that the `Maximum Internet name and password` setting is not No Access.

Comment: Yeah, the Trust servers is set to other servers. Since I'm running this from my local PC (and local isn't among this group) that's probably what's happening. I think I'll have to bring up the topic of getting me a test server and some more privileges as my signature on these xPages elements aren't included in the run unrestricted methods & operations on these servers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to handle the approach slightly different. Move your SSJS into a library and encapsulate it in a Js object. Something like this:

```
   var lookup = {
          "getClients" : function() {
                 var result;
                 var db = lookup.getDB();
                 if(db) {
                    // do your thing
                 } else {
                   // some error handling
                }
            return result;
         },
      "getDB" : function() {
                var URL = database.getProfileField(...);
  // returns as notes://
 var db;
  try {
       db = session.resolve(URL);
   } catch(e) {
   }
   return db;
       }

   }
```

Pecked on glass, will contain errors.

Only one field needed in the profile and ready to be a bean or cached etc

Comment: Now there's a patch of code I'm having trouble comprehending. (still pretty new to Javascript, not begining something in the SSJS library with function is throwing me and beans is still something I put into chili) I'm wondering if this is a server access issue. Session authentication is disabled on the server under the Domino Web engine tab, and even hostname(s) under HTTP is blank. I think the current Notes admins here are doing everything they can to prevent web access to the servers. I can't even find a domlog.nsf DB and they don't use iNotes here.....

Comment: This is very basic js. By declaring an object var x = {....} you can be sure to call the right function by x.myFunc() which is different from t.myFunc() which is different from myFunc(). Using the getSething() naming convention is highly recommended. However the key point is the session.resolve

Comment: XPiNC uses NRPC, since you can add a view, the problem is elsewhere. Btw add a view datasource and use its getview

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've been absent a couple of days taking MS Virtual Academy's C# course. I'm beginning to understand....

Answer (score 1):

Try using getDatabase(serverName, dbPath, false) instead. I prefer that. With two parameters the object is not null but you still need to check database.isOpen(). I'm not sure if it can still access some properties like filePath without opening, but it won't be able to access a view without opening. With the false third parameter, it returns null.

Comment: Setting "false" leaves the cDb variable null. I think I'm running into a permissions issue, but not being the administrator of this domain, I'm not certain what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a permission issue. Is it going to a different server? If so, remember XPages can only access other servers in the same domain. You can always get the other database using sessionAsSigner and use queryAccessRoles to check access for Anonymous, to check what access it actually has.